# How to crypt mine password in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to crypt mine function and get it back,need your help tell me please what i am doing wrong ?

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE email = 'Natali@gmail.com' AND u_password = crypt(u_password, '@kjvfhjh88976');
// Null result

INSERT INTO users (user_id, nick_name, email, u_password)
VALUES
    (87678655, 'Natali1990@', 'Natali@gmail.com', crypt('@kjvfhjh88976', gen_salt('bf')));


SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = 'Natali@gmail.com'; // Working
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: no result the password not match .. no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `pgcrypto` package incorrectly, and given that it is confusing, this is not a surprise.  Your current insert seems fine:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, nick_name, email, u_password)
VALUES
    (87678655, 'Natali1990@', 'Natali@gmail.com',
        CRYPT('@kjvfhjh88976', GEN_SALT('bf')));
```

Then, to authenticate a user, use a `SELECT` looking something like the following:

```
SELECT u_password = CRYPT('@kjvfhjh88976', u_password)
FROM users
WHERE email = 'Natali@gmail.com';
```

This would return true if the user entered the correct password.  You may read more about this in the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html);

Comment: Just added the stored hashed password after insert .. 
Can't understand what you talking about ..

Comment: Just run the select I gave above.  You need to compare `u_password` against `CRYPT(p1, p2)`, where `p1` is the user's plaintext password, and `p2` is `u_password`.  If they match, then the user is authenticated.

Comment: `Can't understand what you talking about` ... neither could I, for 5-10 minutes, until I figured out how the API works.

Comment: That what i am doing in mine select statement

Comment: No, you're not.  Look again.  You're passing the clear text password as the _second_ parameter.  That's wrong; it should be first.  And the correct second parameter is the `u_password` field.

Comment: Yeah...by the way, most password APIs I have seen (e.g. in Java or PHP) work by taking the cleartext password, and a salt, and then generating the hashed password.  Postgres does this in something of a strange way.  You could avoid this by handling it in your app layer.